# MySQL Select Based On Multiple Table

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Dashboard.idUser, Dashboard.idDashboard, 
Dashboard.text, Dashboard.date, Dashboard.visibility 
FROM Dashboard
JOIN Users_Settings ON Dashboard.idUser = Users_Settings.idUser
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Dashboard.date) >= 0
AND Dashboard.deleted = 0
AND ( Dashboard.idUser IN 
 ( SELECT `idUser_b` FROM Friends WHERE `idUser_a` = 1 ) 
OR Dashboard.idUser IN 
( SELECT `idUser_a` FROM Friends WHERE `idUser_b` = 1) 
OR (Dashboard.idUser = 1) 
OR (Dashboard.visibility = 3 OR (Dashboard.idUser != 1 AND 
    (Dashboard.visibility != 2 AND Dashboard.visibility != 1)))
    )
OR Users_Settings.account_visibility != 1    
HAVING idUser IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Dashboard.date ASC
```

This works...kinda. It will pull results except it wont exclude results of friends or other users where Users_Settings.account_visibility != 1

I have tried various things with this statement to no avail.

Comment: I think you need to change the `OR` to an `AND` in `OR Users_Settings.account_visibility != 1  `

Comment: I tried that but then it wont show any results for the current user. Thats why I have the OR (Dashboard.idUser = 1) Cause I want the logged in users feed also. I use query bindings instead of actual hard values. I don't know maybe I will have to take a different approach?

Comment: maybe `AND (Users_Settings.account_visibility != 1 OR Dashboard.idUser = 1)` assuming idUser 1 is the current user

Comment: Thanks! lol that was it. New it had to be something simple.

Comment: Voted to close as a Typo